# Мы потеряли доступ к аккаунту разработчика Google

Tags: android

Мы потеряли доступ к аккаунту разработчика Google. Нет ни логина ни пароля. Есть только учредительные документы фирмы. Как восстановить доступ?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же, написать в поддержку. Там рассмотрят Вашу заявку и при правильности предоставленных данных вернут доступ к аккаунту.

Answer (score 1):

[Ссылка на справочный центр](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer?source=404#topic=3450769) Там есть пункт связаться с нами.